# SQL - Rails Deep nested joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, tags, include

First of all, I'm French, so sorry for my ugly english.

I have following models :

**Shop**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

**Product**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

**Tagging**

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :product
```

**Tag**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :products, through: :taggings
```

I want to be able to do `Shop.first.tags`, so I want to get all shop's products' tags, in a single request if it's possible. If I could have explanations with, it will be fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not specified a relationship for `tags` on your `Shop` model. You'll need to add that relationship in order to call `#tags` on a single object.

```
class Shop
  # ...
  has_many :tags, :through => :products
  # ...
end
```

Comment: That was so simple... I tried to do something like Shop.joins(products: [taggings: :tags])... Thank you, it works !